# Trying get the price of products with RCurl

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

Im scrapping the price of some products from a website . In Python I used the urllib2 without problems, but when I tried using RCurl in R I couldn't donwload the source code.

I have to paste the source code with the product code, then I catch the price. The path of a product is: http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/code_of_product.

Actually, I can't download the source code of a product with RCurl. When I try for example getURL('http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/111467594') it returns "".

I tried using getURL('.../produtos/111467594') and I could download the source, but in this way I'm unable to get the price. :(

Anyone know how could I get the price of the products?

Thanks.

Ps.: Sorry for my bad english. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

It's hard to say for me why it doesn't work, could you include a `verbose=TRUE` in the `getURL`? Also, I notice there's different prices on the webpage you linked. You want all or just the first? How about this to get the "Por price":

```
library("stringr")

productwebpage<-readLines("http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/111467594")
pricerow<-productwebpage[grep("p class=\"sale price\"",productwebpage)] 
price<-str_extract_all(pricerow,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")[[1]]
```

You could also substitute the `grep("p class=\"sale price\"",productwebpage)` to either `grep("<p><span class=\"regular price\">",productwebpage)` (to get the "de price" / old price) or `grep("<span class=\"p-v interest\">",productwebpage)` (which will give you the "sem jouros" price / per month payment). For the last example you will get the months first and the payment after so it will be:

```
> price
[1] "12"    "83,25"
```

This should hopefully work for other products as well (just tried 5 and seemed to work for all of them).

Comment: @user2080573 If you think that I've answered your questions you could select my post as an answer so that it is clear that this topic have been answered.